# How can I call java functions from native code (using JNI)?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to implement a JNI function that calls a function in Java from native C code. Currently the JNI_createJavaVM method does not exist in my libjvm.so. So i cannot use the JNI API of the form (*env)->[JNI function].

I know I usually cache the JVM from java to native code by writing a JNI_onload function. But what I want is a service called in the order of c->java, rather than java being called first.

Is it possible to import jvm from native code without the help of Java? Or is it possible to call Java functions without JVM from native code?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Any implementation of JVM has all the functions needed to call into java-  there's 0 chance yours doesn't.  And yes, that's the only way to make the call.

Comment: SO frowns on external links, but see [The JNI Cookbook](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo028/c/recipeNo028_redux_main.c) for an example. I'm sure you can find others.

Comment: Please edit your question with evidence that your libjvm.so is defective and how you are testing this.